# Access a method on delegate

Tags: iphone, ios, sqlite, core-data

I am starting to learn iOS and on my app delegate I am handling the databases. As soon as my app runs it load a .sqlite database. What I would like to do is to open a view (which I already have) with two buttons. When I press on I want to load a English database, and when I press the other button I want to load another database.

How can I access the core data functions that are on the delegate to control the load of the SQLite file.

Thanks
Best Regards

Comment: Did you add the database to your project as a localized resource?

Comment: Yes I have to databases on my project. And I am loading them correctly. My problem is that I am loading the database on the delegate, which loads the database as soon as the app runs. I would like to change that and only load the database after a view is presented.

Comment: I understood your question, I was asking how is your database added to your project?  Is the database in a localized resource folder?

Comment: Sorry:) It is located in the resources. I had it to the project folder. Thanks

Comment: Just to tell you that I have access to the managedObjectContext in the viewController. But when the view is loaded the database is already loaded and I don't want that. Thanks

Comment: Do you want iOS to choose the correct database based on the current locale?  Or do you want the user to choose the database?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to familiarize yourself with CoreData and SQLite. http://maniacdev.com/2009/09/iphone-sqlite-vs-core-data-%E2%80%93-which-to-choose

Also, technically, you could conditionally load different databases. Take a look at detecting the user's locale for their current language:

```
[NSLocale currentLocale];
```

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSLocale_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: What is happening is that the methods I have on the delegate are loading a database. What I want is to only load the database when I want. But it is loading on the delegate. Can I change the functions from the delegate to any viewController? Thanks

Comment: How do i set the view controller to be the delegate? Sorry I am new to this :) thanks

Comment: You can't technically move the UIApplicationDelegate methods to another object. Instead, you would need to load your SQLite database or CoreData objects in your viewController. You don't have to load them exclusively in the main app delegate and can load them as you need elsewhere.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. But I am loading the database on one of those methods that I have on the applicationdelegate. On the application delegate I am also getting the context of the database and sending it to the viewcontroller. But at this point the database is already loaded. And I would like to load it only on the view.